# VLOOKUP if 0, find next value

Tags: excel

I have a list like this:

```
Column1, Column2
c,0
c,5
c,0
a,0
a,1
a,0
b,1
b,0
b,0
```

And I want to get the non-zero values for a,b and c. When doing VLOOKUP you get the first value.

i would like to get something like this:

```
a,1
b,1
c,5
```

Comment: Would something like `=sumif(A:A, "a", B:B)` work in your data? It works in your sample data.

Comment: yes, a sumif works if I do it in two steps, but I was wondering if there was a more straight forward way

Answer (score 1):

Use Index with Aggregate to return the position:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$10)/(($A$2:$A$10=D2)*($B$2:$B$10>0)),1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in range `A1:B9`, and unique values in `C1:C3` use this array formula in column `D`:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,IF($B$1:$B$9>0,$A$1:$B$9),2,FALSE)
```

Please take note that array formulas are applied with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.